# Using different jackson ObjectMappers for seperate RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I have a single `@RequestMapping` that consumes a custom MIME type. The request uses an `ObjectMapper` bean defined in the `@Configuration` to enabled the `JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER`.

This feature allows typically invalid json (treating backslashes as a non-special character) to be consumed, which is a requirement of this particular `@RequestMapping` to allow google encoded polylines to be parsed directly. However this means that this ObjectMapper is now being used for *ALL* of my `@RequestMapping` when it is really only a requirement for one.

Is there a way to differentiate the ObjectMapper being used for each `@Controller` or `@RequestMapping`?

**Object Mapper Bean**

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.featuresToEnable(
      JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER);

    return builder.build();
}
```

**Request Mapping Interface Method**

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns the toll cost breakdown for a journey", notes = "", response = TotalCost.class, tags={ "pricing", })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "successful operation", response = TotalCost.class) })
@RequestMapping(value = "/pricing/journeyCost",
    produces = { "application/json" }, 
    consumes = { "application/vnd.toll-pricing+json" },
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<TotalCost> getTollBreakdownFromEncodedPoly(@ApiParam(value = "Request object representing the journey" ,required=true ) @RequestBody Journey body);
```

Comment: Do you want the custom handling for just the Journey interface?

Comment: @lexknuther essentially yes.

Comment: Also, what version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: Here you can find possible solution to your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691392/spring-boot-different-objectmapper-instances-for-request-and-response/45157169

Comment: @lexknuther 2.6.6

Comment: @SzymonStepniak thanks, I ended up basically using your answer in that question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in another stackoverflow question linked to me by another user - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45157169/2073800

I just had to add the following `@Bean` to my `@Configuration`

```
@Bean
public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.featuresToEnable(
      JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER);

    final AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build());
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.toll-pricing+json")));

    return new HttpMessageConverters(converter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've a custom MIME type, then you can register a custom [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) that uses a special `ObjectMapper` for your MIME type, and returns `false` from `canRead/canWrite` for regular MIME types. You register your custom `HttpMessageConverter` like so:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
      List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        messageConverters.add(myCustomMessageConverter());

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

Think of it as related to content negotiation, and not related to URL mapping; URL mapping (`@RequestMapping`) is meant for finding a handler, not for choosing what marshaller/unmarshaller to use.

Comment: Understanding content negotiation and a comment on my question pointed me in the right direction. I don't doubt the above solution would have worked, but I found something slightly easier.

Comment: @Jags I looked at what Szymon Stepniak had in the other thread, and it's exactly similar to what I said, except for the part how you register the converter. When you say you don't doubt the above would've worked, I doubt that you don't really understand what's going on.

Comment: I don't disagree that your answers are similar, however his answer was much easier to follow and better explained. I also agree that I probably don't understand completely the intricacies, but maybe that is also a reflection on the quality of your answer? I applied your answer, and from my understanding I created a custom implement of a `HttpMessageConverter` and overrode the methods to only accept one `MediaType`. Szymons answer was much more succinct and straightforward.